# how to initialize an object of subclass with an "existing object of superclass" in objective-C

Tags: objective-c, inheritance, subclass, init, superclass

I have subclassed NSException class to create CustomException class.

Whenever I catch an exception in code (in  @catch), i want to initialize an object of CustomException (subclass of NSException) with the object of NSException that is passed as a parameter to @catch.

Something like this

```
@catch (NSException * e) {

CustomException * ex1=[[CustomException alloc]initWithException:e errorCode:@"-11011" severity:1];
}
```

I tried doing it by passing the NSException object to the init method of CustomException.
(i replaced the [super init] with the passed NSException object as given below)

```
//initializer for CustomException
-(id) initWithException:(id)originalException errorCode: (NSString *)errorCode severity:(NSInteger)errorSeverity{

    //self = [super initWithName: name reason:@"" userInfo:nil];
    self=originalException;
    self.code=errorCode;
    self.severity=errorSeverity;

    return self;
}
```

This doen't work! How can I achieve this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to do something which generally[*] isn't supported in any OO language - convert an instance of a class into an instance of one of its subclasses.

Your assignment `self=originalException` is just (type incorrect) pointer assignment (which the compiler and runtime will *not* check as you've used `id` as the type) - this won't make `CustomException` out of an `NSException`.

To achieve what you want replace `self=originalException` with

```
[super initWithName:[originalException name]
       reason:[originalException reason]
       userInfo:[originalException userInfo]]
```

and then continue to initialize the fields you've added in `CustomException`.

---

[*] In Objective-C it *is* possible in some cases to correctly convert a class instance into a subclass instance, but **don't do it** without very very very very good reason. And if you don't know how you shouldn't even be thinking of it ;-)

Comment: OO doesn't support down-casting a parent concrete type to a child type. However, this question is talking about copying. In C++, you can answer this question like this: http://cpp.sh/3ar6m

Answer (score 0):

```
self = originalException;
```

When you do that you are just assigning a `NSException` object to your `NSCustomException` so
the following things will happen:

- You might get a warning when doing
  the assignment since
  `CustomException` is expected but you
  are passing just a `NSException`
  object ;(
- After that, the compiler will think that `self`
  is a `CustomException` object so it
  won't complain when calling some
  methods of `CustomException` class
  but it will crash when reaching
  those.

You should enable `initWithName:reason:userinfo:` and don't do the assignment.